# Compare non integers with if

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to look through a file with one column of decimal numbers and find all the entries that are (+ or -) 2.2 of 100 and redirect them to a file. This is what I got so far.

```
cat numfile.txt

100.56
99.6
96.8
86.77
105.7
95.5
92.4
101.1
102.5
98.7
```

Here is what I have been trying

```
while read line
  do
    num=2.2

    if [ $line -ge $num ] 
      then 
        echo $line > savefile.txt
    fi
  done < numfile.txt
```

Desired output

```
cat savefile.txt

100.56
99.6
101.1
98.7
```

Comment: Why you choose answer from Mike Wodarczyk ? I answered the first, I propouse two different approach. Mark answered wrongly and after my comment take my approach into own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend sending the comparison computation through "bc".

For example

```
  result=$(echo "scale=2;  ( $line >= 100 - $num )  &&  ($line <= 100 + $num  ) " | bc)
```

$result will be "0" if false and "1" if the statement is true.
Your if statement would look like this:

```
 if [ $(echo "scale=2;  ( $line >= 100 - $num )  &&  ($line <= 100 + $num  ) " | bc) -eq 1 ] ; 
     then 
         ... # do true stuff
  fi
```

Comment: question is not $line > $num. $line is 100+/-$num

Comment: @Mike Wodarczyk perfect thanks for the help !!! if you dont mind i have one final question. How do you do multiple (while read line) in the same script with out the variable line conflicting ech other?

Comment: You can just use a different variable name other than line.   While read Aline; do ...  while read bline; do ...  the variables would be aline and bline.  I don't recommend using the names aline and bline, but something  that makes sense for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

May be is not better but works:

```
 if [ `echo "scale=2;sqrt((100-$line)^2)<=$num" | bc` -eq 1 ]
```

Another way:

```
num=2.2
awk '{if (sqrt((100-$1)^2) < '$num') { print $1}}' < numfile.txt > savefile.txt
```

Comment: at first glance this code appears to contradict itself.

Comment: 1. bash support only integer. 2. Neither bc nor awk not has abs function.

Comment: You can make an abs function in bc like this:     printf "scale=2;\ndefine myabs ( x )  { \n if ( x > 0 )  return x; \n  return -1 * x; \n };\n myabs ( -11.3 ) \n"  | bc

Answer (score 0):

Mixing the two approaches a bit:

```
c=2.2

while read n; do
    (( $(bc -l <<< "sqrt(($n-100)^2) <= $c") )) && echo $n
done < numfile.txt > savefile.txt
```

The `(( ))` conditional evaluates to true if its contents are unequal to zero, and `bc` prints `1` if a conditional evaluates to true.

The `-l` option defines the math library, which enables the `sqrt` function, and sets `scale` to `20`.

I've moved the redirection to outside of the loop to avoid having to open and close the file descriptor each time.